# Как установить cocos2d v3.4.9 на xcode 7

Tags: ios, cocos2d, cocos

Подскажите, пожалуйста, пошаговый мануал по установке кокоса на икскод

Все, что есть в сети – это или версия 2 или еще старее.

И эта инфа уже не подходит под новый коксо. Пробовал просто написал

```
./install.sh -f
```

Вроде как попал в установку, но почти сразу она прекратилась такими строками

> mv: rename путь to путь No such file on directory

Comment: а с github чем не нравится? https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-objc

Comment: Так я от туда архивом и скачал...

Comment: смотрите ответ.

Comment: Для меня это все пока очень не понятным кажется. Можем ли мы связаться в скайпе: Proof_mail и вы мне все расскажете. Даже за вознаграждение

Comment: добавил в ответ.

Comment: если ответ вам подошел, вы можете принять его нажав галочку слева от ответа.

Answer (score 1):

Проще всего скачать [темплейт](https://github.com/slembcke/UnofficialCocos2DTemplate) и переименовать.

Использование:

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/slembcke/UnofficialCocos2DTemplate.git
cd UnofficialCocos2DTemplate
./RenameProject.rb
```

Скрипт запросит новое имя для проекта. Потом в xcode сделать find/replace чтоб переименовать классы.

Как этот проект потом положить в git:

Темплейт привязан к репозиторию для темплейта, если вам надо сложить проект обратно в git измените origin, чтобы он указывал на ваш репозиторий.

```
git remote set-url origin MyRepositoryURL
git pull origin
git push
```

Answer (score -1):

Вместо `./install.sh -f` нужно было поставить `./install.sh -i`, после чего установка прошла на ура.